# LanguageDetectionError in transliterate library | Can't detect english language?

Tags: python

I have one problem. Let me try to explain this little problem.

I use [transliterate library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/transliterate) in my Django project. User can write `english (latin)` or `russian (cyrillic)` letters in field. If user write russian words it change word to latin letters but if user write english words I see next error:

```
LanguageDetectionError: Can't detect language for the text "document" given.
```

I use this code:

```
transliterate.translit(field_value, reversed=True)
```

Also I notice that in that project its impossible to detect english language, isn't it?

`transliterate.detect_language(field_value)` return `None` when user enter english word.

My aim is to transliterate only if user wrote russion word, but don't touch it user wrote english word. What can you advice?

Right now I found library which can help me to detect language: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/langdetect
Who worked with this library?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try detecting English and then moving on to assume Russian? I put some Russian news articles into the Python code listed below. It clearly detected that it is not English.

It's pretty simple code that can be easily applied.

[isEnglish github](https://github.com/jsfakianos/isEnglish)